# setting dashed inline style in erb file

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, erb

How to set dashed inline css attributes inside an `erb` file. For instance, this

```
<%= image_tag "some_image.png", html: {width: "some_width", height: "some_height", margin:"some_margin"}%>
```

this works fine but when I set

```
<%= image_tag "some_image.png", html: {width: "some_width", height: "some_height", margin-left:"some_margin_left"}%>
```

I get

```
syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your inline way:

```
<%= image_tag "dtm_logo.png", 
   html: {width: "10px", height: "40px", :"margin-left" => "9px"} %>
```

Separating your html and css to separate files :

```
<%= image_tag "your_image.png", id: 'image_id' %>
```

make sure 'your_image.png' file resides in your app/assets/images folder.

put this css code to your application.css.
keeping css related attributes in your .html.erb template is not a clean approach.

#application.css

```
#image_id {
  margin: 20px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 30px; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this error because symbol literal with dash (`-`, like `:margin-left`) is not valid symbol.
It should be:

```
:"margin-left" => "some_margin_left"
```

also, this syntax should work:

```
margin: {left: "some_margin_left"}
```